# How to retain list numbers when hiding overflow?

Tags: css

I've got an HTML ordered list whose items contain a short "name" and a long "info" of which I would like to display only the first part so that the items use only a single line, sort of like a truncated preview.  The image below demonstrates the desired effect:

[image: Demonstration of preview effect]

I can basically achieve the effect by using the HTML/CSS below; however, the list numbers disappear!  See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgteox4e/1/) for a demonstration.

Here is my attempted code:

```css
.name { font-weight: bold; }
.info { color: #ccc; }

li { /* Why do the LI numbers disappear? */
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li><span class="name">Foo</span>: <span class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque lobortis ligula quis mi ultrices fringilla. Suspendisse sed commodo magna. Curabitur cursus non tellus vel dapibus. Integer facilisis sollicitudin velit vel aliquet. Aenean sit amet leo id neque suscipit volutpat sed blandit metus.</span></li>
    <li><span class="name">Bar</span>: <span class="info">Nullam non posuere tortor. Sed facilisis nibh et maximus interdum. Vivamus eleifend lectus varius rutrum vehicula. Ut sit amet dictum tortor, auctor fringilla nibh. Aenean imperdiet suscipit suscipit. Sed a ex eu purus dapibus venenatis. In ut orci eget libero sollicitudin mollis.</span></li>
</ol>
```

I'm guessing the `overflow: hidden` directive is the culprit but it's also what achieves the desired truncation.  Any ideas how I can display only a single truncated line of text per list item while retaining the numbering?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the position of the list number using:

```css
.name {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.info {
    color: #ccc;
}
li {
    /* Why do the LI numbers disappear? */
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 500px;
}
ol {
    list-style-position:inside;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li><span class="name">Foo</span>: <span class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque lobortis ligula quis mi ultrices fringilla. Suspendisse sed commodo magna. Curabitur cursus non tellus vel dapibus. Integer facilisis sollicitudin velit vel aliquet. Aenean sit amet leo id neque suscipit volutpat sed blandit metus.</span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="name">Bar</span>: <span class="info">Nullam non posuere tortor. Sed facilisis nibh et maximus interdum. Vivamus eleifend lectus varius rutrum vehicula. Ut sit amet dictum tortor, auctor fringilla nibh. Aenean imperdiet suscipit suscipit. Sed a ex eu purus dapibus venenatis. In ut orci eget libero sollicitudin mollis.</span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This is a good solution; however, when the list contains ten or more items they are not properly left-hand aligned since the list item numbers vary in width.  Good grief, CSS =|